# laravel field with no default value

Tags: php, laravel

i have a small problem here and it is that the image field doesn't have a default value as the complier said but actually i assigned a value for it i know that this error pops up when the field should have a value but the programmer didn't assign a value to it i know all of this but i already assigned a value to my field so what i am missing here

controller

```
protected function validator(array $data)

    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'image' => ['required' , 'image' , 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg', 'max:2048'],
        ]);
    }
 protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        request()->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'image' => $imageName,
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <label  class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" >Upload a picture</label>
                            <div class="custom-file mb-3 col-sm-6">
                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input center" id="image" name="image">
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile"></label>
                            </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

the problem is mainly from the controller but i said that i put the view just in case you want to see it

small note : the image is uploading and it is stored at public folder just like the code said but its name doesn't save at the database also the field image is string at my database because i just want its name so i could view it

snap shot

[image: the error message]

Comment: can you post the migration for the table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a default image for your image field. Also make sure  you have made it fillable, if not set it in  `protected $fillable` in your model `User.php`

> You will get this error when a user doesn't upload an image.

```
$table->string('image')->default('default.jpg');//You can also add .png
```

Now have a default image in your storage with name *default.jpg*
This way the image will have a default value if user doesn't' upload it.

Comment: Perfect thank you very much what i was missing is that i didn't put it in the user model as fillable and just a note instead of doing default.jpg i could make it nullable() but as i said before i want it to have a name so i could display it later

Comment: If you make it `nullable`, make sure you do an if in your view before accessing `$user->image` . Having `default.jpg` is good option, if you want to give user a profile image.

Comment: and also i put it as required so that the user cannot move without uploading it + thanks to laravel powerfull kernel even if the user tried to bybass it using special tools like burb suite or that kind of tools the kernerl will refuse the request

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the default value or make that field null in the migration file, not the controller or view.

```
$table->string('image')->nullable();
```

or...

```
$table->string('image')->default('value');
```

Comment: i know this treak bro but i wamt it to have data not just null

Comment: ok do ```dd($imageName)``` after this line;
```$imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();``` and lets see the response

Comment: nice idea and as the dd said it is working correctly that the image name is displayed like this "1561333059.jpg" which is what i am expecting so the code is working correctly untill it reaches the create method i think there is something wrong with it maybe the syntax or smthg but i cannot find it also just like what i added to the question the image is stored in my public folder but it is not storing in my database

Comment: why not use the ```new User()``` function instead of ```User::create()```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help i fixed it just like the last answer suggests and about the new user() i didn't do it because i will have to rewrite all the function with a diffrent formula and this is not good as this function belongs to the register function so that if another programmer saw my code he will not get the point of it